# How to split a gene into 2 genes based on the `anndata.obs['sample']` values?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Can someone help me and tell me how to split a gene into 2 genes based on the `anndata.obs['sample']` values?
(https://github.com/theislab/anndata)
Because there are 2 transgenic genes and most of the sequences are the same, which can't be separated during alignment.
Those 2 genes are in different samples so I want to split them in the anndata file. Thanks a lot.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way in AnnData to do it, but we can manipulate the numpy array and pandas data frames then create a new AnnData with the added row for the new gene we added manually.

This should be a reproducible example:

```py
    from anndata import AnnData
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    #-- Create minimal reproducible example
    gene_exp = np.array([[0,32,0,1], [1,2,1,34], [65,2,4,1]])
    adata = AnnData(gene_exp)
    adata.obs['annot'] = ['g1.1', 'g1.1', 'g1.2']
    adata.var['gene'] = ['g'+str(i) for i in range(4)]
    
    #-- Select gene and duplicate in matrix
    idx = np.where(adata.var['gene'] == 'g1') # gene to be split into 2
    idx_full = np.append(np.array([i for i in range(adata.n_vars)]), idx)
    new_gexp = adata.X[:,idx_full]
    
    #-- 'Split' expression by 'annot'
    idx_samp = adata.obs['annot'] == 'g1.1'
    new_gexp[idx_samp,-1] = 0
    new_gexp[~idx_samp,idx] = 0
    
    #-- Create new adata
    new_var = adata.var
    new_var.iloc[idx, 0] = 'g1.1'
    new_var = new_var.append({'gene': 'g1.2'}, ignore_index = True)
    adata_new = AnnData(new_gexp)
    adata_new.var = new_var
    adata_new.obs = adata.obs
```

Comment: That is really helpfull. Thank you very much!